# How to use a variable in a substitution?

Tags: perl

I've a text file and I want to match and erase the following text (please note the newline):

```
[ From:
http://www.website.com ]
```

The following code works

```
$text =~ s/\[.*\]//ms;
```

This other doesn't

```
my $patt = \[.*\];
$text =~ s/$patt//ms;
```

Would someone be so kind to explain me why?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would an unquoted string "work"? And please be more specific than [`It doesn't work`](http://tlp-perl.blogspot.se/2013/06/its-not-working.html)

Comment: You're perfectly right, my "it doesn't work" means that the code doesn't match anything so the text is not removed.

Comment: Yes, that is a fair guess. However, you have a multiline input, which might be the problem if you are reading from a file or similar.

Answer (score 3):

The second variant works perfectly, if you quote the pattern string and get rid of syntax error:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = qq{a[ From:
http://www.website.com ]b};

my $patt = qr/\[.*?\]/s;
$text =~ s/$patt//;

print $text;
```

Prints:

```
ab
```

I added ? quantifier to the regexp to make the replacement ungreedy. And removed `m` modifier, because you are not using ^ and $ in your regexp, so m is useless.

Comment: … but you should probably use regex quotes `my $pat = qr/\[.*\]/` for uniform parsing rules of the regex. Also, OP probably wants the `*?` quantifier.

Comment: @amon Answer improved. Thank you.

Comment: @amon: I think not. It's now too far away from the OP's original, and it looks like it's saying that the reason for the problem is that `qr/../` wasn't used. There really is no point in using them here anyway, as the regex in `$patt` is stringified again, interpolated into the substitution, and recompiled. What does *"for uniform parsing rules of the regex"* mean?

Comment: @Borodin you have a point. I meant that strings and regexes *can* be parsed differently (which is not the case here). To prevent future frustration, I find it easier to state “Always use `qr//` quotes for regexes” instead of “You can use normal quotes for regexes, but these are the differences to regexes: …” which is followed by a list of backslash handling, interpolation semantics, and special regex constructs in `qr`, `q` and `qq` quotes. My above comment just contained two style opinions.

Comment: @Borodin: I'm fairly sure that `s/$patt//` is smart enough not to recompile the pattern if `$patt` is precompiled using `qr//`. Certainly that's the case for `m/$patt/`, and I see no reason why `s/$patt//` would be different.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Is that documented anywhere? `$str =~ m/$pattern/` is the same as `$str =~ $pattern` if $pattern is a compiled regex, so it's an unnecessary optimisation, and in cases like `$str =~ m/^($pattern)/` I think it would *have* to recompile.

Comment: @Borodin: For `m//`, it's documented in perlop. I'm not sure if it's documented anywhere for `s///`, or indeed even if it's true; I might have to check the source. (Also, I vaguely recall reading somewhere that even `m/^$pattern/` might be optimized to some degree, but I have no real idea if that's actually true or not. In principle, though, the regexp compiler _could_ optimize it by embedding `$pattern` directly as a subpattern without having to stringify and recompile it.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen you can use the `re` pragma to see what *actually* happens. `s/$re//` works without recompilation, unlike `s/^$pattern//` (in v16.2): `perl -Mre=Debug,COMPILE,PARSE -e'my $re = qr/a/; s/$re/b/;'`. If you anchor the `s///` at the beginning, no visible reuse occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason your variation isn't working is that you haven't put quotes around your `$patt` string. As it is it throws a syntax error. This works fine

```
my $patt = '\[.*\]';
$text =~ s/$patt//ms;
```

My only comment is that the `/m` modifier is superfluous as it modifies the behaviour of the `$` and `^` anchors, which you aren't using here. Only `/s` is necessary to make the `.` match newline characters.

Comment: Indeed. I've rechecked my code, I had actually quoted the pattern, but I had used the “"” symbol, so the statement matched the pattern partially, matching only the first “.” in the hyperlink and removing it.

Comment: @Daniele. Yes, double quotes will swallow the backslashes before the square brackets and leave you with an entirely different regex that matches just a single dot or asterisk. It's best to print a string that's misbehaving to see what's actually in it, or - even better - use `Data::Dump` to display it.